# Graph API: What is the correct way to interrupt Pagination

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using this script to fetch Chats. I need 100 chats maximum but it may happen that a chat do not have 100 messages. How can I handle that case in this script?

I am using Node Package Microsoft Graph Client.

```js
    const { Client, PageIterator } = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');
    async getChatList(GroupChatId) {
        let messages = [];

        let count = 0;
        let pauseAfter = 100; // 100 messages limit

        let response = await this.graphClient
            .api(`/chats/${GroupChatId}/messages`)
            .version('beta')
            .get();


        let callback = (data) => {
            messages.push(data);
            count++;
            return count < pauseAfter;
        }

        let pageIterator = new PageIterator(this.graphClient, response, callback);
        await pageIterator.iterate();

        return messages;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered on the [GitHub issue you opened](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/8683), the iterator should stop all by itself if it runs out of items to iterate before hitting your "maximum". However, I think you're hitting a bug in the specific API you're using `/chats/id/messages`.

The problem is that this API is returning a `nextLink` value in it's response even if there are no next pages. It shouldn't be, and I'm reporting that to the Teams folks. That's causing the pageIterator to try to get the next set of results, which returns 0 items and a `nextLink`. You're stuck in an infinite loop.

So because of this, using the pageIterator just won't work for this API. You'll need to do the iteration yourself. Here's some TypeScript code to show it:

```js
let keepGoing: Boolean = true;
do
{
  // If there are no items in the page, then stop
  // iterating.
  keepGoing = currentPage.value.length > 0;

  // Loop through the current page
  currentPage.value.forEach((message) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(message.id));
  });

  // If there's a next link follow it
  if (keepGoing && !isNullOrUndefined(currentPage["@odata.nextLink"]))
  {
    currentPage = await client
      .api(currentPage["@odata.nextLink"])
      .get();
  }
} while (keepGoing);
```

Comment: Yes, the infinite loop is the problem. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with a conditional statement if the message has value or not.

The pseudo code is given below:

```
let callback = (data) => {

    if(data != "" || data != null)
    {
       messages.push(data);
       count++;
       return count < pauseAfter;
    }
   else{
      return;
   }

}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I can give you more information if you can help me out.

Comment: We will definitely help you if you give more information but from the question I have written a pseudo code  and You need to try on your own with proper testing.

Comment: `let callback = (data) =>  { .... }`

Once the last message is reached, flow does not go into callback and pageIterator does not stop.

Here is the complete function: https://pastebin.com/eBttdEGF

Comment: In declaration of variable name response add filters to remove messages which are null.For Example : **.filter('body/content'  eq null)**. Please go through [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) for more details